# Create hive table error to load Twitter data

Tags: hadoop, twitter, hive, flume, bigdata

I am trying to create external table and trying to load twitter data into table. While creating the table I am getting following error and could not able to track the error.

```
hive> ADD JAR /usr/local/hive/lib/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    > ;
Added [/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar] to class path
Added resources: [/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar]
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tweets (
    >    id BIGINT,
    >    created_at STRING,
    >    source STRING,
    >    favorited BOOLEAN,
    >    retweeted_status STRUCT<
    >      text:STRING,
    >      user:STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>,
    >      retweet_count:INT>,
    >    entities STRUCT<
    >      urls:ARRAY<STRUCT<expanded_url:STRING>>,
    >      user_mentions:ARRAY<STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
    >      hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,
    >    text STRING,
    >    user STRUCT<
    >      screen_name:STRING,
    >      name:STRING,
    >      friends_count:INT,
    >      followers_count:INT,
    >      statuses_count:INT,
    >      verified:BOOLEAN,
    >      utc_offset:INT,
    >      time_zone:STRING>,
    >    in_reply_to_screen_name STRING
    >  )
    >  PARTITIONED BY (datehour INT)
    >  ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
    >  LOCATION '/user/flume/tweets/01092015';
```

below is the error

```
FailedPredicateException(identifier,{useSQL11ReservedKeywordsForIdentifier()}?)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.identifier(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:10924)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.identifier(HiveParser.java:45850)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameColonType(HiveParser.java:38211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameColonTypeList(HiveParser.java:36342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.structType(HiveParser.java:39707)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.type(HiveParser.java:38655)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.colType(HiveParser.java:38367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameType(HiveParser.java:38051)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameTypeList(HiveParser.java:36203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.createTableStatement(HiveParser.java:5214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.ddlStatement(HiveParser.java:2640)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1650)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:308)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:736)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:681)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:621)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
FAILED: ParseException line 9:2 Failed to recognize predicate 'user'. Failed rule: 'identifier' in column specification.
```

And below is the twitter data that is available in the hdfs path. How to create proper table for the below twitter data?

```
{
    "extended_entities": {
        "media": [{
            "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/9SoA83sVvP",
            "indices": [100, 123],
            "sizes": {
                "small": {
                    "w": 340,
                    "h": 340,
                    "resize": "fit"
                },
                "large": {
                    "w": 480,
                    "h": 480,
                    "resize": "fit"
                },
                "thumb": {
                    "w": 150,
                    "h": 150,
                    "resize": "crop"
                },
                "medium": {
                    "w": 480,
                    "h": 480,
                    "resize": "fit"
                }
            },
            "id_str": "685710180164579329",
            "expanded_url": "http://twitter.com/add7dave/status/685710518456209408/video/1",
            "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/ext_tw_video_thumb/685710180164579329/pu/img/4wOqavTprNIaMgjK.jpg",
            "id": 685710180164579329,
            "type": "video",
            "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/ext_tw_video_thumb/685710180164579329/pu/img/4wOqavTprNIaMgjK.jpg",
            "url": "https://t.co/9SoA83sVvP",
            "video_info": {
                "aspect_ratio": [1, 1],
                "duration_millis": 7567,
                "variants": [{
                    "content_type": "application/x-mpegURL",
                    "url": "https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/685710180164579329/pu/pl/6JnchC_1FWviydJV.m3u8"
                }, {
                    "content_type": "application/dash+xml",
                    "url": "https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/685710180164579329/pu/pl/6JnchC_1FWviydJV.mpd"
                }, {
                    "content_type": "video/mp4",
                    "bitrate": 320000,
                    "url": "https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/685710180164579329/pu/vid/240x240/W7suov-YC1Iq1-QT.mp4"
                }, {
                    "content_type": "video/webm",
                    "bitrate": 832000,
                    "url": "https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/685710180164579329/pu/vid/480x480/bDG_UfEw3jBM7z4e.webm"
                }, {
                    "content_type": "video/mp4",
                    "bitrate": 832000,
                    "url": "https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/685710180164579329/pu/vid/480x480/bDG_UfEw3jBM7z4e.mp4"
                }]
            }
        }]
    },
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "created_at": "Sat Jan 09 06:31:42 +0000 2016",
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/android\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for Android<\/a>",
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "retweeted": false,
    "geo": null,
    "filter_level": "low",
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "is_quote_status": false,
    "id_str": "685710518456209408",
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "favorite_count": 0,
    "id": 685710518456209408,
    "text": "New video NO-17\n#BritanniaFilmfareAwards\n@GoodDayCookies\n@BritanniaIndLtd\nAmitabh Bachchan dialogue https://t.co/9SoA83sVvP",
    "place": null,
    "lang": "en",
    "favorited": false,
    "possibly_sensitive": false,
    "coordinates": null,
    "truncated": false,
    "timestamp_ms": "1452321102142",
    "entities": {
        "urls": [],
        "hashtags": [{
            "indices": [16, 40],
            "text": "BritanniaFilmfareAwards"
        }],
        "media": [{
            "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/9SoA83sVvP",
            "indices": [100, 123],
            "sizes": {
                "small": {
                    "w": 340,
                    "h": 340,
                    "resize": "fit"
                },
                "large": {
                    "w": 480,
                    "h": 480,
                    "resize": "fit"
                },
                "thumb": {
                    "w": 150,
                    "h": 150,
                    "resize": "crop"
                },
                "medium": {
                    "w": 480,
                    "h": 480,
                    "resize": "fit"
                }
            },
            "id_str": "685710180164579329",
            "expanded_url": "http://twitter.com/add7dave/status/685710518456209408/video/1",
            "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/ext_tw_video_thumb/685710180164579329/pu/img/4wOqavTprNIaMgjK.jpg",
            "id": 685710180164579329,
            "type": "photo",
            "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/ext_tw_video_thumb/685710180164579329/pu/img/4wOqavTprNIaMgjK.jpg",
            "url": "https://t.co/9SoA83sVvP"
        }],
        "user_mentions": [{
            "indices": [41, 56],
            "screen_name": "GoodDayCookies",
            "id_str": "2197439803",
            "name": "Britannia Good Day",
            "id": 2197439803
        }, {
            "indices": [57, 73],
            "screen_name": "BritanniaIndLtd",
            "id_str": "3281245460",
            "name": "Britannia Industries",
            "id": 3281245460
        }],
        "symbols": []
    },
    "contributors": null,
    "user": {
        "utc_offset": 19800,
        "friends_count": 1517,
        "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/593327096736256001/TT8Ds75__normal.jpg",
        "listed_count": 1,
        "profile_background_image_url": "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme19/bg.gif",
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "favourites_count": 25,
        "description": "Sharukhan, Kapil sharma , Narendra modi Fan (Supporter) be happy *↓*",
        "created_at": "Thu Sep 15 08:04:58 +0000 2011",
        "is_translator": false,
        "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme19/bg.gif",
        "protected": false,
        "screen_name": "add7dave",
        "id_str": "373836462",
        "profile_link_color": "9266CC",
        "id": 373836462,
        "geo_enabled": false,
        "profile_background_color": "FFF04D",
        "lang": "en",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "000000",
        "profile_text_color": "000000",
        "verified": false,
        "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/593327096736256001/TT8Ds75__normal.jpg",
        "time_zone": "Chennai",
        "url": null,
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "profile_background_tile": false,
        "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/373836462/1428993069",
        "statuses_count": 21397,
        "follow_request_sent": null,
        "followers_count": 438,
        "profile_use_background_image": true,
        "default_profile": false,
        "following": null,
        "name": "aditya dave",
        "location": "Bhavnagar, Gujarat",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "000000",
        "notifications": null
    }
}
```

Comment: It's probably best to split this into two questions and raise a new question for the second part about Twitter.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use this to disable the check :

```
SET hive.support.sql11.reserved.keywords=false;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL you can see a list of reserved keywords, of which `user` is one. You can't name a column `user`.

You can name it `` `user` `` if you want, and then your queries would look like

```
SELECT `user` FROM table;
```

but as you can see that's a bit ugly so it's probably better to pick a different column name.