# Create hive table for JSON data

Tags: hadoop, twitter, hive, flume, bigdata

How to create hive table for the below twitter JSON data that is available in HDFS path. I tried some of the query from the web to create the table, but facing some issue.

```
{
    "extended_entities": {
        "media": [{
            "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/9SoA83sVvP",
            "indices": [100, 123],
            "sizes": {
                "small": {
                    "w": 340,
                    "h": 340,
                    "resize": "fit"
                },
                "large": {
                    "w": 480,
                    "h": 480,
                    "resize": "fit"
                },
                "thumb": {
                    "w": 150,
                    "h": 150,
                    "resize": "crop"
                },
                "medium": {
                    "w": 480,
                    "h": 480,
                    "resize": "fit"
                }
            },
            "id_str": "685710180164579329",
            "expanded_url": "http://twitter.com/add7dave/status/685710518456209408/video/1",
            "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/ext_tw_video_thumb/685710180164579329/pu/img/4wOqavTprNIaMgjK.jpg",
            "id": 685710180164579329,
            "type": "video",
            "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/ext_tw_video_thumb/685710180164579329/pu/img/4wOqavTprNIaMgjK.jpg",
            "url": "https://t.co/9SoA83sVvP",
            "video_info": {
                "aspect_ratio": [1, 1],
                "duration_millis": 7567,
                "variants": [{
                    "content_type": "application/x-mpegURL",
                    "url": "https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/685710180164579329/pu/pl/6JnchC_1FWviydJV.m3u8"
                }, {
                    "content_type": "application/dash+xml",
                    "url": "https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/685710180164579329/pu/pl/6JnchC_1FWviydJV.mpd"
                }, {
                    "content_type": "video/mp4",
                    "bitrate": 320000,
                    "url": "https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/685710180164579329/pu/vid/240x240/W7suov-YC1Iq1-QT.mp4"
                }, {
                    "content_type": "video/webm",
                    "bitrate": 832000,
                    "url": "https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/685710180164579329/pu/vid/480x480/bDG_UfEw3jBM7z4e.webm"
                }, {
                    "content_type": "video/mp4",
                    "bitrate": 832000,
                    "url": "https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/685710180164579329/pu/vid/480x480/bDG_UfEw3jBM7z4e.mp4"
                }]
            }
        }]
    },
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "created_at": "Sat Jan 09 06:31:42 +0000 2016",
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/android\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for Android<\/a>",
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "retweeted": false,
    "geo": null,
    "filter_level": "low",
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "is_quote_status": false,
    "id_str": "685710518456209408",
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "favorite_count": 0,
    "id": 685710518456209408,
    "text": "New video NO-17\n#BritanniaFilmfareAwards\n@GoodDayCookies\n@BritanniaIndLtd\nAmitabh Bachchan dialogue https://t.co/9SoA83sVvP",
    "place": null,
    "lang": "en",
    "favorited": false,
    "possibly_sensitive": false,
    "coordinates": null,
    "truncated": false,
    "timestamp_ms": "1452321102142",
    "entities": {
        "urls": [],
        "hashtags": [{
            "indices": [16, 40],
            "text": "BritanniaFilmfareAwards"
        }],
        "media": [{
            "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/9SoA83sVvP",
            "indices": [100, 123],
            "sizes": {
                "small": {
                    "w": 340,
                    "h": 340,
                    "resize": "fit"
                },
                "large": {
                    "w": 480,
                    "h": 480,
                    "resize": "fit"
                },
                "thumb": {
                    "w": 150,
                    "h": 150,
                    "resize": "crop"
                },
                "medium": {
                    "w": 480,
                    "h": 480,
                    "resize": "fit"
                }
            },
            "id_str": "685710180164579329",
            "expanded_url": "http://twitter.com/add7dave/status/685710518456209408/video/1",
            "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/ext_tw_video_thumb/685710180164579329/pu/img/4wOqavTprNIaMgjK.jpg",
            "id": 685710180164579329,
            "type": "photo",
            "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/ext_tw_video_thumb/685710180164579329/pu/img/4wOqavTprNIaMgjK.jpg",
            "url": "https://t.co/9SoA83sVvP"
        }],
        "user_mentions": [{
            "indices": [41, 56],
            "screen_name": "GoodDayCookies",
            "id_str": "2197439803",
            "name": "Britannia Good Day",
            "id": 2197439803
        }, {
            "indices": [57, 73],
            "screen_name": "BritanniaIndLtd",
            "id_str": "3281245460",
            "name": "Britannia Industries",
            "id": 3281245460
        }],
        "symbols": []
    },
    "contributors": null,
    "user": {
        "utc_offset": 19800,
        "friends_count": 1517,
        "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/593327096736256001/TT8Ds75__normal.jpg",
        "listed_count": 1,
        "profile_background_image_url": "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme19/bg.gif",
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "favourites_count": 25,
        "description": "Sharukhan, Kapil sharma , Narendra modi Fan (Supporter) be happy *↓*",
        "created_at": "Thu Sep 15 08:04:58 +0000 2011",
        "is_translator": false,
        "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme19/bg.gif",
        "protected": false,
        "screen_name": "add7dave",
        "id_str": "373836462",
        "profile_link_color": "9266CC",
        "id": 373836462,
        "geo_enabled": false,
        "profile_background_color": "FFF04D",
        "lang": "en",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "000000",
        "profile_text_color": "000000",
        "verified": false,
        "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/593327096736256001/TT8Ds75__normal.jpg",
        "time_zone": "Chennai",
        "url": null,
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "profile_background_tile": false,
        "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/373836462/1428993069",
        "statuses_count": 21397,
        "follow_request_sent": null,
        "followers_count": 438,
        "profile_use_background_image": true,
        "default_profile": false,
        "following": null,
        "name": "aditya dave",
        "location": "Bhavnagar, Gujarat",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "000000",
        "notifications": null
    }
}
```

I tried the below table but it gives error.

```
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tweets (
    id BIGINT,
    created_at STRING,
    source STRING,
    favorited BOOLEAN,
    retweeted_status STRUCT<
      text:STRING,
      user:STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>,
      retweet_count:INT>,
    entities STRUCT<
      urls:ARRAY<STRUCT<expanded_url:STRING>>,
      user_mentions:ARRAY<STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
      hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,
    text STRING,
    user STRUCT<
      screen_name:STRING,
      name:STRING,
      friends_count:INT,
      followers_count:INT,
      statuses_count:INT,
      verified:BOOLEAN,
      utc_offset:INT,
      time_zone:STRING>,
    in_reply_to_screen_name STRING
  )
  PARTITIONED BY (datehour INT)
  ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
  LOCATION '/user/flume/tweets/01092015';
```

Comment: Could you post the error you get?

Comment: FailedPredicateException(identifier,{useSQL11ReservedKeywordsForIdentifier()}?)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.identifier(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:10924)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.identifier(HiveParser.java:45850)  FAILED: ParseException line 9:2 Failed to recognize predicate 'user'. Failed rule: 'identifier' in column specification.

Comment: I think `user` is a keyword and you are using it as a column name, that is what might be causing the issue..

Comment: I answered this question for you last night http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696792/create-hive-table-error-to-load-twitter-data, and you've ignored it and just posted the same question again now? That's quite rude.

Comment: I already explain how to create a table for twitter data in Hive, [follow this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35809205/how-to-read-data-files-generated-by-flume-from-twitter/35826883#35826883)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this utility https://github.com/quux00/hive-json-schema to create a hive schema from JSON.   But as [Ben Watson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729819/ben-watson) in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696792/create-hive-table-error-to-load-twitter-data) if there are some columns like `user` that use a reserved name, you have to either enclose them with backticks or use a serde like https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde that can map hive columns to json elements.