# How to read data files generated by flume from twitter

Tags: hadoop, twitter, flume

I have generated few twitter data log files using flume on HDFS , what is the actual format of the log file ? I was expecting data in json format. But it looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjwAD.png). Could someone help me on how to read this data ? or what is wrong with the way I have done this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOWNLOAD THE FILE (hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar) from this link  
 http://files.cloudera.com/samples/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Then put this file in  your $HIVE_HOME/lib  
Add the jar into hive shell

```
hive> ADD JAR file:///home/hadoop/work/hive-0.10.0/lib/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Create a table in hive

```
hive> CREATE TABLE tweets (
id BIGINT,
created_at STRING,
source STRING,
favorited BOOLEAN,
retweeted_status STRUCT<
text:STRING,
user:STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>,
retweet_count:INT>,
entities STRUCT<
urls:ARRAY<STRUCT<expanded_url:STRING>>,
user_mentions:ARRAY<STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,
text STRING,
user STRUCT<
screen_name:STRING,
name:STRING,
friends_count:INT,
followers_count:INT,
statuses_count:INT,
verified:BOOLEAN,
utc_offset:INT,
time_zone:STRING>,
in_reply_to_screen_name STRING
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe';
```

load data into table from hdfs

```
hive> load data inpath '/home/hadoop/work/flumedata' into table tweets;
```

Now analyze you twitter data from this table

```
hive> select id,text,user from tweets;
```

you done, but it is deserialized data, now serialize from hive table..

Comment: Thank you very much , This is what I was looking at .

Answer (score 0):

create a table using with serde in hive then load the twitter log data into hive table. then analyze it.

Comment: Did you see the image of data I was getting? does it actually look like that ?